# Expand search bar equally on both sides

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to make it look like this (the white box at the end of both sides is basically the continuation of the search-box):

[image]

I tried different ways to make it equally long on both left and right sides (to center it under my title) but unfortunately it always resulted in failure. The left side didn't move and the right side just became wider.

I'm looking as well for a way to add some space between the arrow icon and the right border of the search-box. I tried adding some padding but it didn't work.

```css
.help-container {
  padding: 5rem 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: #dadbf1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.searchTerm {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  outline: none;
  color: #9dbfaf;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: url("https://svgur.com/i/qJh.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="help-container">
    <div class="help">
      <h1>How can we help?</h1>
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/686579/pen/zYJYPWB

Comment: I see you are using display flex. To center using flex, you can to set the container object to diplay: flex, then use margin: auto on the item you want be centered in the container.

Comment: @BransonSmith Unfortunately it didn't work. Basically I'm just trying to make my search bar wider than it's title, equally long on both sides. After trying to change width or adding padding, it always increases on the right-side while the left-side doesn't move.

Comment: @Hillow Aww I see, In that case, you may need to widen the containers that contain the title and the search. So in this case, "help-container" and "help" need to be wider (at least as wide as the search is going to be). A good start could be to set width to 100vw (full width of screen) for both containers, and then setting the width of the title and search to something else (like 50vw and 90vw) but all those specific values can change later. Basically, your current code is trying to make the search bar wider than the component it is contained in so it is "overflowing" to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make the search bigger than the nodes/elements that contain it.

Make sure to set the width of the containing components to something bigger.

To center using `display: flex;`, you can set a container to use flex, and then use `margin: auto;` in the child element to automatically center with the containing-flexed-element.

Here is updated html that gives a class to each container. Notice I added class="search-background" so I can give that element a width.

example.html

```html
<section>
    <div class="help-container">
        <div class="help">
        <h1>How can we help?</h1>
        <div class="search-background" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="search">
            <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is updated css with display flex on all containing elements (and flex direction of column so that things are displayed vertically, display flex defaults to horizontal)

Containers have `display: flex;`, centered items have `margin: auto;`
You can customize the actual widths of each element to your desire. Use margin to adjust the element right or left. margin "auto" just tells it to fill the difference between the parent and child element's width.

example.css

```css
.help-container {
    padding: 5rem 0;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    background-color: #dadbf1;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  
.help {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
.search-background {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

  .search {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  .searchTerm {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    outline: none;
    color: #9dbfaf;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-image: url("https://svgur.com/i/qJh.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    background-size: 30px;
  }
```

Here's a screenshot of it on my machine. The red border is only there to help visualize the container needed to be adjusted.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may add this rule to the `.search` container:

```
.search::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - (2 * 3em));
  height: var(--height);
  padding: var(--padding);
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

So that you have a pseudo element bound to the `<input>` container that will be positioned `absolute` while having `width: 100%` minus an arbitrary amount being your padding.

I also zeroed the padding/margin on `html, body` and used custom variables to hold the padding and height you are using on your input so that it will be replicated on the pseudo element.

This long route was required to have a separated element to style with different criteria using css alone.

```css
html, body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.help-container {
  padding: 5rem 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: #dadbf1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.search {
  --height: 45px;
  --padding: 5px;

  width: 100%;
  /*position: relative;*/
  display: flex;  
}

.searchTerm {

  height: var(--height);
  padding: var(--padding);    
  z-index: 2;

  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;  
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  outline: none;
  
  color: #9dbfaf;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: url("https://svgur.com/i/qJh.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-size: 30px;
}

.search::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - (2 * 3em));
  height: var(--height);
  padding: var(--padding);
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="help-container">
    <div class="help">
      <h1>How can we help?</h1>
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a div before `searchbar` with an inline CSS to let you see what I added, and deleted `width: 100%` in searchbar. That is why it was not centered

```css
.help-container {
  padding: 5rem 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: #dadbf1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.search {
  padding: 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.searchTerm {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  outline: none;
  color: #9dbfaf;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: url("https://svgur.com/i/qJh.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="help-container">
    <div class="help">
      <h1>How can we help?</h1>
      <div style="background-color: white;">
        <div class="search">
          <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `input` `width` for 80% instead 100% and use `justify-content` to center the `input` and for adding a white space in your bg-input try using percentages instead `right`. If you want to know more about it check how to use [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).

```css
.help-container {
  padding: 5rem 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: #dadbf1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}

.searchTerm {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  outline: none;
  color: #9dbfaf;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: url('https://svgur.com/i/qJh.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% center;
  background-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="help-container">
    <div class="help">
      <h1>How can we help?</h1>
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```